# Minecraft Items De spawning

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im Minecraft PE I died but then I went to Save and Quit without retrieving my items. Will my items disappear even if I saved and quit or will they stay there until I re-login?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel you should make that an official answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're on a server, the game will pause until you rejoin your world. Dropped items (without their data being tampered with) will despawn in 300 ticks, or five minutes.